# Matching mysql Live database with Replication database

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

Friends,

I am trapped into an issue please suggest.

I have one Live database and one replication database. Both databases are on different server. Yesterday my replication get stopped for 4hrs and then started back after 4 hours.
Now there is mismatch of data from live database and replication database.

Now how can i syncronize my replication database with live database for missing transactions.

Comment: You can use some sqlyog for this. It has one way database synchronization.

Comment: Seems good, But i am not sure if it will work because its a huge database and syncronizing data like this may take a long time.

Comment: You can try with some test databases and check.

Comment: elaborate your problem little bit as if replication was stopped (reason of stopping) and again started then there should not be any issue as replication will start to sync data from the pointer where it leave...also which engine you are using..